# Scala and Eclipse: Export as Jar File, but cannot find main method

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, jar

I have a problem exporting a scala project as a .jar file and then run it using a command in the cmd. The file takes a port number as its parameter, because it establishes a TCP connection between a server and a client. There are three files:

- Engine.scala = object containing the main method: Starts a web server (waits for input query from a html file and transfers it to a text processing server) and a text processing server (this will take the query and search an inverted index of a text file (alice in wonderland ;) and return all the lines of the text file, in which the query terms occur).
- TextProcessingServer: does the query search
- WebServer: waits for query input

When I start it in eclipse and pass a port number (8090 in my case), everything works fine and I can query my server using a web site.

However, if I try to export it, it doesn't work anymore. To export it to a jar, I do the following:

1. in eclipse, I export it by: Export -> Java -> JAR File -> 1234.jar and check "Export all output folders for checked projects" and "Export Java source files and resources".
2. In the command line, I type:
   java -cp 1234.jar:lib/scala-library.jar assignment1.Engine 8090

Now I get the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class assignment1.Engine
```

Versions used:

```
Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK (Version Indigo)

Build id: 3.0.1-vfinal-20130718-1727-Typesafe
```

Can anybody help me? I have tried almost everything suggested on the internet, like adapting the Manifest etc. but nothing seems to work. It will just not find the main method :(

What I already noticed when I run it in Eclipse is that I cannot choose "run as Scala application", I can only run it as Java application. Don't know if that is of any importance...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're from Distributed Systems HS2013, right? :-D

The problem is, that in the command line you're typing `lib/scala-library.jar` but you're not providing the scala library in the same folder as your jar is in.
If your jar is on the Desktop you need to copy the folder `lib` from your scala installation to the Desktop or you just provide the scala-library.jar (than you type `scala-library.jar` instead of `lib/scala-library.jar`).
If you're using Windows you should replace the `:` with a `;` so it looks like this:

```
java -cp 1234.jar;lib/scala-library.jar assignment1.Engine 8090
```

It will probably not find your text file though, so you have to copy it to the same folder (e.g. Desktop) as well.

Comment: Well, apparently you were looking for the same ;) Thanks a lot, was a real pain in the neck...